# Error creating bean with name 'transactionRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb, crud

I am trying to integrate DynamoDB locally to my Spring Boot project.
It used to be with Spring Data JPA and now I am trying to switch to Spring Data Dynamo DB

I added this line to the property file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

---

the repository:

```
@EnableScan
public interface TransactionRepository extends CrudRepository<Transaction, Long> {
}
```

---

the entity definition

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Transaction")
public class Transaction {

    private long id;
    /**
     * Transaction category
     */
    Category category;

    /** Transaction amount */
    double amount;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    Transaction() {
        this.setAmount(0);
        this.setCategory(Category.OTHER);
    }

    public Transaction(double amount, Category category) {
        this.setAmount(amount);
        this.setCategory(category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Default constructor should be public, instead of package private in your case for the class Transaction.

Comment: I did, but it doesnt solve the problem ...

Comment: are you able to fix this problem?

Comment: DynamoDB and JPA are a bad mix. things should be done on a low level ...